# Looking for mysql performance test tool that can specify query, number of threads, frequency, time of test

Tags: mysql, performance, testing, load

I want to check spec of CPU and IOPS needed for DB server by doing performance test to MySQL

could you tell me if you know any MySQL performance test tool that can do the following:

- can specify query
  　 - I want to use "join" and "where" in the query to use in the test, so
- can specify number of threads
- can specify frequency to send query
  　 - There is a query that has to be sent 110 times in a second, whereas there is a query that has to be sent once in 20seconds
- can specify a time of test
  　 - I want to run the test for 3 minutes

Comment: sysbench?  There are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JMeter to simulate scenario you want.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html